# Android XML error while generating signed .apk file

Tags: android

I've not opened this particular project for about 3 months but when I tried to generate a signed .apk file, **I get this one error only:**

```
C:\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_newanswers.xml:57: Error: The id "linearLayout2" is not defined anywhere. [UnknownId]
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
```

**Here's my current code in that xml file:**

```
<TextView
        android:text="OptionView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOptionTitle"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtOptionTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false">
<!--
        <TextView
            android:text="QuestionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestionTitle"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
-->
        <com.rokonoid.widget.ExpandableTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestionTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.bozapro.circularsliderrange.CircularSliderRange
                android:id="@+id/cirAns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="343dp"
                circular:start_angle="270"
                circular:end_angle="300"
                circular:start_thumb_size="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="75dp"
                android:paddingRight="75dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="5%"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/txtPercent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:text="Back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnQnsBack"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnQnsNext"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Funny thing is, it worked multiple times previously and I did not make any changes at all. I can also rebuild and clean build it without errors. Oddly, my backup versions which are Identical, generate this ONE same error for my 6 different xml files here:

```
Error:(5) Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
```

It points to this line in each of the 6 files:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

My guess is I'm not calling something in the MainActivity (but that would not explain why it has always worked -with fully functioning .apk) Any thoughts?

Thanks heaps!
James

Comment: the problem here is that you dont have a layout with id 'linearLayout2', but you are trying to access it. Try removing android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2" from your textview

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
```

From

```
<TextView
            android:text="5%"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/txtPercent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
```

As i see no layout with id linearLayout2 in your file above. Errors of such kind are not generated in the debug build but in the realease build.

Comment: Good to know. Plz mark the answer as correct so it can be helpful to others too. Also plz upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Malik Ahhsan said, just remove the `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"`

Comment: Perfect guys! It actually worked. Simply removing it. I don't know why it was added in the first place during .apk generation.

Comment: @solodeveloper Good luck my friend :)